# List files changed in a single commit to remote branch

Tags: git

how can I list the names of the files(only) which are changed as part of a single commit(the latest commit/HEAD) to a remote/upstream branch without doing a git pull to local of that branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't strictly need to `pull` (as in, merge the remote branch into your local version), but at the very least you'll have to `fetch` to get fresh definitions :

```
git fetch
git log --name-only --no-walk --pretty=format:"" <upstreamBranch>
```

where `<upstreamBranch>` might be for example `origin/master`

*(Note : your local branches won't be modified, only the remote-tracking branches used to record the state of remote branches)*

*(Another note : if the file list is empty, the last commit is likely a merge commit.)*

Comment: When using --no-walk, it is not displaying any files that are changed. If I omit --no-walk, it lists all the files which are changed till date for the branch. But, what I need is to list only the names of the files which are changed in the last commit of the upstream branch

Comment: @KumarjitGhosh Thing is, if the last commit on the remote branch happens to be a merge commit, no files are actually modified *by that very commit*, only by the earlier commits that this merge makes reachable. So in this case, it's expected not to have any output. `--no-walk` is preventing `log` from outputting all the commit's ancestry, only the commit itself (last one on the given ref, `<upstreamBranch>`)

Comment: My sincere apologies, yes your observation is correct. We are using --no-ff merge strategy, and the latest commit in the repository is for a merge action. In such cases, when I check for the merge commit in the enterprise url, I can see changed files, however the same does not get reflected when I use the --no-walk option. In actuality, this merge commit has the same set of files that are changed for it's parent commit. In such cases, how can I get the list of changed files as seen in the github enterprise url? Thanks.